# double data inserted in sql c#

Tags: c#, sql

This is just a simple way of registering new account credentials. My problem is that whenever I click the save button, the data will be saved twice in the database.

[Sample image  of the double entry in the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgKxc.png)

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = ("INSERT INTO Tbl_Staff (Name,pos,username,password) VALUES (@name,@pos,@username,@password)");

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", textBox4.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox2.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox3.Text);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

                        // Check Error
                        if (result > 0)
                            MessageBox.Show("Credentials has been successfully added.","" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        textBox1.Text = "";
                        textBox2.Text = "";
                        textBox3.Text = "";
                        textBox4.Text = "";
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Add primary key to the table

Comment: @M. Hassan How do you know that the table doesn't have a primary key? I assume you meant "unique index".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` twice.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Owww! My bad. Thank you.

Comment: @VVN Why do you say that?

Answer (score 1):

you excecute the query twice.
change:

```
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to

```
con.Open();
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```